# Why Node.js inherit implement by ObjectSetPrototypeOf(A.prototype, B.prototype); and ObjectSetPrototypeOf(A, B);

Tags: node.js, inheritance, prototype

I find Node.js implement inherit in this way, for example:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js

```
ObjectSetPrototypeOf(ServerResponse.prototype, OutgoingMessage.prototype);   // line 174
ObjectSetPrototypeOf(ServerResponse, OutgoingMessage);  // line 175
```

instead of only seting prototype:

```
ObjectSetPrototypeOf(ServerResponse.prototype, OutgoingMessage.prototype);
```

Answer (score 1):

So that the static methods of the parent class are inherited by the subclass, because they've made the parent class constructor the prototype of the child class constructor.

Native `class` syntax does the same thing:

```js
class Parent {
    static example() {
        console.log("Parent.example");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
}

console.log(Child.example());                 // "Parent.example"
console.log(Child.hasOwnProperty("example")); // false
console.log("example" in Child);              // true, because it's inherited
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Child) === Parent); // true
```

Remember that functions are objects. Objects can have prototypes. An object inherits properties from its prototype. In the example above, `Child` (the function objects) has `Parent` (the function object) as its prototype, so it inherits the `example` property. Up through ES5, a function created with JavaScript code always had `Function.prototype` as its prototype, but starting with ES2015, that's not always true. `class` syntax makes the superclass constructor the prototype of the subclass constructor. You can also change the prototype of a function after it's created, via `Object.setPrototypeOf`, but it's usually best to avoid changing the prototype of an existing object.

In Chapter 4 of my new book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, I use the following example to illustrate this concept (details omitted):

```
class Color {
}
class ColorWithAlpha {
}
```

along with this diagram to show the two parallel prototype chains created by that, one for the constructor functions themselves, and the other for the objects they assign as prototype when used to create objects:

[image]

Comment: console.log(Child.prototype.prototype); 
// Got undefined,why it is not Parent.prototype ?

Comment: @ZhenchuanRen - Because `Child.prototype` doesn't have a `prototype` property (for instance, it isn't a constructor function). You may be confusing the prototype of an object (which you can get via `Object.getPrototypeOf`) and the `prototype` property of constructor functions, which is **not** their prototype, it's the object that's used as the prototype of objects created with the constructor function via `new`.

Comment: You are right. I use  console.log(Child.prototype.__proto__);  and I got the Parent.prototype.   However, I still don't undersatnd why static methods defined in Parent function can be inherited by ObjectSetPrototypeOf(Child, Parent);

Comment: @ZhenchuanRen - Functions are objects. Objects can have prototypes. An object inherits properties from its prototype. Up through ES5, a function created with JavaScript code always had `Function.prototype` as its prototype, but starting with ES2015, that's not always true. `class` syntax makes the superclass constructor the prototype of the subclass constructor. (You can also change the prototype of a function after it's created, via `Object.setPrototypeOf`, but it's usually best to avoid changing the prototype of an existing object.)

Comment: Thank your help,  I think I understand the principle behind this question. ``Object.setPrototypeOf(Child, Parent)`` changes Child's ``__proto__`` , instead of changing ``Child.prototype``.  So Child could use the static methods in Parent Function.

Comment: @ZhenchuanRen - Yes, that's right. (But avoid using `__proto__`, it's a legacy compatibility feature that's only defined for JavaScript in web browsers [although V8 always provides it], and it's only defined for objects that inherit [directly or indirectly] from `Object.prototype`. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`.)